# How do I pass the value instead of the reference of an array?

Tags: javascript, object

I have this structure:

```
var a = [];
a.push({"level": 1, "column": 4, "parent": "none", "title": "Node 0", "content": "Parintele suprem", "show": "1"});
var b = a;

a.push({"level": 1, "column": 5, "parent": "none", "title": "Node 1", "content": "Parintele suprem", "show": "1"});

console.log(b);
```

Now the problem is that `b` has the exact content as `a` (the content after the second push). This suggest (correct me if I'm wrong) that when I said `b = a` I actually gave b same reference as a, so whatever I do in `a` I have in `b`. The thing is that I need to pass the value. So I have the previews `a`, value in `b`.

Edit to make the question more clear: How do I pass the value instead of the reference?

Comment: "The thing is that I need to pass the value. So I have the previews a value in b.". Or to spell it like a question: "How do I pass the value instead of the referance?".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you can use this to copy the value instead of the reference:

```
var b = a.slice(0);
```

**EDIT**
As the comments have mentioned and it's also mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

*slice* does not alter the original array, but returns a new "one level deep" copy that contains copies of the elements sliced from the original array. Elements of the original array are copied into the new array as follows:

- For object references (and not the actual object), slice copies
  **object references** into the new array. Both the original and new array
  refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes
  are visible to both the new and original arrays.
- For strings and numbers (not String and Number objects), slice copies
  **strings and numbers** into the new array. Changes to the string or
  number in one array does not affect the other array.

If a new element is added to either array, the other array is not affected.

Comment: Works like a dream :). I can't accept the answer yet, but I will in 7 minutes (when stack will allow me).

Comment: Seems so. I'll make a quick test after I finish current task :). Also since there are more than 1 valid answers I'll make a post answering witch would be faster... from my quick test seems like slice. But since I don't have a logical explanation I can't be sure.

Comment: @zozo. Note that it will work only for arrays and not for objects. see my answer.

Comment: Correct... but I can't use prototype and unless clone is faster I don't have any use to make a clone function since the slice fits my current needs. +1 tho.

Comment: +1 Note that the behavior of `slice` if you give it **no** arguments [is not defined in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.10), and so `var b = a.slice();` is relying on unspecified, undocumented behavior. To avoid relying on that, just pass `0`: `var b = a.slice(0);`

Comment: @RobAgar: Correct, only *array index* properties are copied; [see the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.10). If the array instance has other properties, they will not be copied.

Answer (score 7):

you can implement a *clone* method as follow:

```
function clone(source) {
    var result = source, i, len;
    if (!source
        || source instanceof Number
        || source instanceof String
        || source instanceof Boolean) {
        return result;
    } else if (Object.prototype.toString.call(source).slice(8,-1) === 'Array') {
        result = [];
        var resultLen = 0;
        for (i = 0, len = source.length; i < len; i++) {
            result[resultLen++] = clone(source[i]);
        }
    } else if (typeof source == 'object') {
        result = {};
        for (i in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                result[i] = clone(source[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

then:

```
var b = clone(a);
```

if you are sure that a is Array, only use Niklas's:

```
var b = a.slice();
```

ps: my english is poor:)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way i could find is to just make a json string and then parse the data.

```
var assiging_variable = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(source_array));
```

This also works if the source array is a multidimensional array, the `array.slice(0)` method does not work for multidimensional array.

Comment: It is indeed the easiest. Although not the most optimal ;). Still +1. It is rather interesting no1 mentioned this before :)).

Comment: I'm sad that is the only solution which worked for me...
I was iterating from array A and filtering , removing and adding objects and properties to array B and this is the only thing which worked for me .
I'm coming from Python and I don't use to all of the NodeJS\JavaScript unique thinking.

Comment: let obj_A = Object.assign({}, obj_B );

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's the way reference assignment works in javascript.  You want to *clone* the object to make a copy, which is unfortunately more involved than it should be.  Frameworks like MooTools provide the simplest solution, or you can roll your own `clone` function.

Answer (score 1):

I found a nicer way by using "Object.assign({}, source_object )":

```
let source_obj  = {val1:"A",val2:"B"};
let copy_obj = Object.assign({}, source_obj);
```