# Which way is faster to copy an array of objects: slice or clone?

Tags: javascript, clone, slice

This is related to: [How do I pass the value instead of the refererence of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190518/javascript-eqals-between-objects-or-array-of-objects-copies-referance/9190599#9190599)

I need to send the value instead of reference to an array. To that question I got 2-3 valid answers. One was use slice, second (and third was similar) was to use clone or make my own clone function.

From a (very) quick test, it seems like slice was faster (tested on a 100,000 elements array). But I don't have any explanation for that.

Can anyone clarify if and why is slice faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `clone` function presented in that answer is very general *(also quite poor; never, ever, **ever** add enumerable properties to `Object.prototype`, and there are other issues as well)*, and is implemented in JavaScript. In contrast, the `slice` answer uses the JavaScript engine's built-in function, which can be written in highly optimized machine code. (Or not, of course.)